# Checking that $\cdot: D_{2n}\times \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ given by $(\alpha , i) \mapsto\sigma_{\alpha}(i)$ is a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-actions, dihedral-groups

My question is on an example of a group action given in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (example 4, p.43):

> If we fix a labeling of the vertices of a regular $n$-gon, each element $\alpha$ of $D_{2n}$ gives rise to a permutation $\sigma_{\alpha}$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ by the way the symmetry $\alpha$ permutes the corresponding vertices. The map of $D_{2n} \times \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ onto $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ defined by $(\alpha,i) \rightarrow \sigma_{\alpha}(i)$ defines a group action of $D_{2n}$ on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}...$

I'm just trying to verify that the map $(\alpha,i) \rightarrow \sigma_{\alpha}(i)$ is indeed a group action. If we let $1$ denote the identity element of $D_{2n}$, then clearly $\sigma_1$ should correspond to the identity permutation, so $\sigma_1(i) = i$ for all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. This confirms the first property of a group action. Then if we let $*$ denote the binary operation on $D_{2n}$ and $\cdot$ the group action, we just have to verify that for all $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in D_{2n}$ and all $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$,
$$ \alpha_1 \cdot (\alpha_2 \cdot i) = (\alpha_1 * \alpha_2) \cdot i.$$

Now
\begin{align*}
    \alpha_1 \cdot (\alpha_2 \cdot i) &= \sigma_{\alpha_1}(\sigma_{\alpha_2}(i)) && (\text{by defn of } \cdot) \\[4pt]
     &= (\sigma_{\alpha_1} \circ \sigma_{\alpha_2})(i) && (\text{defn of } \circ)
\end{align*}

And
\begin{align*}
   (\alpha_1 * \alpha_2) \cdot i = \sigma_{\alpha_1 * \alpha_2}(i). && (\text{Defn of } \cdot)
\end{align*}

Now am I allowed to assert that $\sigma_{\alpha_1 * \alpha_2} = \sigma_{\alpha_1} \circ \sigma_{\alpha_2}$, and thus $\sigma_{\alpha_1 * \alpha_2}(i) = (\sigma_{\alpha_1} \circ \sigma_{\alpha_2})(i)$?

If I had to justify this, I would say something like the following: Pick an $n$-gon and label its vertices; call this the "original" $n$-gon with the "original labeling" of the vertices. If we rotate or reflect the original $n$-gon, this corresponds to a permutation $\alpha_1$ of the original labeling of the vertices. Then if we apply another rotation/reflection to this newly rotated/reflected $n$-gon, the resulting symmetry (relative to the original $n$-gon) corresponds to the map $\alpha_2 \circ \alpha_1$ (relative to the original labeling of the vertices). Is my reasoning here correct?

Is my argument solid enough, or is there a more rigorous way of expressing this? Is there anything that I'm missing?

(I think my uncertainty stems partly from the fact that Dummit and Foote distinguish between the group $D_{2n}$ and the group of permutations to which the elements of $D_{2n}$ correspond, which I find a tad confusing. Perhaps I am just overthinking things...)

A follow-up question: 
The text goes on to say

> Note that this action is faithful: distinct symmetries of a regular $n$-gon induce distinct permutations of the vertices.

Is this supposed to be accepted as "obvious" (I would be ok with that), or is there a rigorous algebraic way of showing this? i.e. if $\alpha_1, \alpha_2 \in D_{2n}$ and $\sigma_{\alpha_1} = \sigma_{\alpha_2}$, how would we show that this implies $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$? Could we just say that $D_{2n}$ is isomorphic to the set of permutations to which the elements of $D_{2n}$ correspond (hence showing that book's claim)?

(Apologies if these are silly questions. Algebra is not my strong suit...)

Comment: Just my thoughts. When they say *"defined by $(\alpha,i)\to\sigma_\alpha(i)$"*, I read it as: $\alpha\cdot i:=\sigma_\alpha(i)$, which assumes that the map $\sigma_\alpha$ *is known*. Such a knowledge should come from the previous *"gives rise"*, which I read as $\sigma_\alpha(i):=\alpha\cdot i$ ("*by the way the symmetry etc.*"), and we are jammed into a circular argument. I think that the geometric def. of $D_{2n}$ assumes as a matter of (geometric) fact that $\alpha\cdot i$ *is* an action, whence $\sigma_\alpha:=\alpha\cdot\_\in S_n$ and $\alpha\mapsto\sigma_\alpha$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I agree that the *definition* of $\alpha \cdot i$ is $\sigma_{\alpha}(i)$; that's how I interpreted it at least. As for the "each element $\alpha$ of $D_{2n}$ *gives rise* to a permutation $\sigma_{\alpha}$" part, I don't believe this is saying $\sigma_{\alpha}(i) := \alpha \cdot i$; rather, I think it's just saying that there is a (one-to-one) correspondence between the symmetries of the regular $n$-gon and a certain set of permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n \}$, where $\sigma_{\alpha}$ denotes the permutation that corresponds to the symmetry $\alpha$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some rows trying to make (more) clear the situation described in the question. First of all, we need a handy notation, and clear definition of the action.

---

Some words on the described action first. It involves $D_n$ in the notation from [Dihedral group, wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group), the dihedral group of all plane symmetries that invariate the set of the vertices of a fixed $n$-gon. And these vertices, labelled by $1,2,\dots,n$. Let us denote by $[n]$ this set of $n$ vertices. Then the given (to-be-)action is a map first:
$$
D_n\times [n]\to [n]\ .
$$
If this is (soon) an action, then it is an action of the group $D_n$ on the set $[n]$. And there is no need to consider permutations of $[n]$ (and/or the group of permutation of $[n]$ and/or the image of $D_n$ inside this group of permutations).
Maybe the example in *loc. cit.* wants to do something with the permutation $\sigma_\alpha$ associated to some symmetry $\alpha$ of the plane containing the vertices of the $n$-gon. But for the question, we just do not need this notational complication.

The map above is defined by $(\alpha,i)\to\alpha\cdot i:=\alpha(i)$.
Here, $\alpha(i)$ is the result of applying the symmetry (= isometric transformation, which is in particular a function) $\alpha$ on the vertex $i$.

Let us check, that this leads to an action. For the identic map id (the neutral element in $D_n$), and for symmetries $\alpha,\beta$ and some vertex $i$ we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{id}\cdot i
&=
\operatorname{id}(i)=i\ ,
\\[3mm]
(\alpha\circ\beta)\cdot i
&=(\alpha\circ\beta)(i)\\
&=\alpha(\beta(i))\\
&=\alpha\cdot(\beta(i))\\
&=\alpha\cdot(\beta\cdot i)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So we have indeed an action, and the above is all regarding a proof.

---

The action is faithful for $n>1$. (For $n\ge 3$ this follows from the fact that an affine plane is "determined by a triple of points", i.e. by fixing an origin and two unit vectors from the origin, a first one and a second one. For $n=2$ - just in case we really want to consider a "$2$-gon", the reflection w.r.t. the line through the two points is fixing pointwise the two vertices, so the action is not faithful. The case $n=1$ is also not coming with a faithful action.)

---

In case we really want to work with permutations, then the group of permutations acting on $[n]$ is the image $\sigma(D_n)$ of $D_n$ inside the permutation group of the set $[n]$ via the map $\alpha\to\sigma_\alpha$, and this action is defined by transport of structure, i.e. $\sigma_\alpha\cdot i :=\alpha\cdot i:=\alpha(i)$. (By transport, it is also an action on the set $[n]$.)

Comment: What does ensure that $(\alpha\circ\beta)(i)=\alpha(\beta(i))$ ?

Comment: @CAB The composition of two function $\alpha,\beta$ is the function $\alpha\circ\beta$ defined by $(\alpha\circ\beta)(i):=\alpha(\beta(i))$.

Comment: @dan_fulea: Thanks for your answer! I've reread it several times, and things are starting to click. The following comment was especially helpful: "Here, $\alpha(i)$ is the result of applying the symmetry (= isometric transformation, which is in particular a function) $\alpha$ on the vertex $i$." In hindsight, this should have been "obvious", but the textbook never actually stated that. Having established that $\alpha(i)$ is a *function*, I am then comfortable with the composition step of your proof: $(\alpha \circ \beta)(i) = \alpha(\beta(i))$.

Comment: @dan_fulea: I just find it a bit odd that the book doesn't just say: "Symmetries are permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n \}$." Perhaps it just wants to emphasize the geometric interpretation of symmetries?  It does say the following: "Now make $D_{2n}$ into a group by defining $st$ for $s,t \in D_{2n}$ to be the symmetry obtained by first applying $t$ then $s$ to the $n$-gon (note that we are viewing symmetries as functions on the $n$-gon, so $st$ is just function composition--read as usual from right to left)..."

Comment: "...If $s,t$ effect the permutations $\sigma$, $\tau$, respectively on the vertices, then $st$ effects $\sigma \circ \tau$."

Comment: @Leonidas Usually, when "working with geometric objects" it is natural to see them in a "specific geometric category". So from the perspective of geometry, if we fix an $n$-gon in the plane (with $n\ge 3$), it is clear that its center will be fixed by each symmetry (whatever it will be at the end), so it is "better" to think about the symmety as a linear map, we work in the category of linear maps, all geometric aids (like diagonaly, mid points of sides, centroids of specific shapes, etc.) will then be mapped correspondingly. But such a map is *determined* by the permutation on the vertices...

Comment: @Leonidas ... and when we want to show something about compositions of such symmetries, like equality of objects, it is enough to look how the specific action looks like on the geometric objects which are the vertices. (Sometimes we may want to look at other geometric related objects, like sides, orientation, etc. - but for the purposes of this question it is enough to look at the permutation associated by the action on the vertices. We "forget" (functorially) that there is a lot of geometry, and isolate the structure which is enough to decide the issue...)